# I want to union together four queries and set this to be the repeater's data source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Based on user design I have to union together four queries and put them in a repeater.

```
 var qryIssuer = from l in dbRRSP.LOA
                        join lrb in dbRRSP.LOAOrReferredBy on l.LOAOrReferredById equals lrb.LoaOrReferredById
                        join lat in dbRRSP.LOAAccessType on l.LOAAccessTypeId equals lat.LOAAccessTypeId
                        join iss in dbRRSP.Issuer on l.IssuerId equals iss.IssuerId
                        where
                            l.PersonId == personId
                        select new
                                   {
                                       LOAOrReferredByDescription = lrb.LoaOrReferredByDescription, 
                                       lat.LOAAccessTypeDescription,
                                       PersonType = "Issuer",
                                       LOAName = iss.CompanyName, 
                                       l.DateAdded
                                   };
          var qryEMD = from l in dbRRSP.LOA
                        join lrb in dbRRSP.LOAOrReferredBy on l.LOAOrReferredById equals lrb.LoaOrReferredById
                        join lat in dbRRSP.LOAAccessType on l.LOAAccessTypeId equals lat.LOAAccessTypeId
                        join emd in dbRRSP.Agent on l.AgentId equals emd.AgentId
                        where
                            l.PersonId == personId
                        select new 
                                    {
                                        LOAOrReferredByDescription = lrb.LoaOrReferredByDescription, 
                                        lat.LOAAccessTypeDescription,
                                        PersonType = "EMD",
                                        LOAName = emd.CompanyName, 
                                        l.DateAdded
                                    };

        var qryEmdRep = from l in dbRRSP.LOA
                        join lrb in dbRRSP.LOAOrReferredBy on l.LOAOrReferredById equals lrb.LoaOrReferredById
                        join lat in dbRRSP.LOAAccessType on l.LOAAccessTypeId equals lat.LOAAccessTypeId
                        join ar in dbRRSP.AgentRepresentative on l.EMDRepresentativeId equals ar.AgentRepresentativeId
                        join arp in dbRRSP.Person on ar.PersonId equals arp.PersonId
                        where
                            l.PersonId == personId
                        select new 
                                   {
                                       LOAOrReferredByDescription = lrb.LoaOrReferredByDescription, 
                                       lat.LOAAccessTypeDescription,
                                       PersonType = "EMD Rep",
                                       LOAName = arp.FirstName + ' ' + arp.LastName, l.DateAdded
                                   };

        var qryLOAPerson = from l in dbRRSP.LOA
                           join lrb in dbRRSP.LOAOrReferredBy on l.LOAOrReferredById equals lrb.LoaOrReferredById
                           join lat in dbRRSP.LOAAccessType on l.LOAAccessTypeId equals lat.LOAAccessTypeId
                           join lp in dbRRSP.LOAPerson on l.LOAPersonId equals lp.LOAPersonId
                           where
                               l.PersonId == personId
                           select new 
                                      {
                                          LOAOrReferredByDescription = lrb.LoaOrReferredByDescription, lat.LOAAccessTypeDescription,
                                          PersonType = "Person",
                                          LOAName = lp.LOAPersonName, 
                                          l.DateAdded
                                      };
```

This is the four queries. And the trickiest part is that the last field is a datetime, which is causing me some issues. I know how to union two of them together like this:

```
var qryMultipleLOA = qryIssuer.Union(qryEMD).ToList().Select(loa => new ExtendedLOA
{
                                                                                  LOAOrReferredByDescription = loa.LOAOrReferredByDescription, 
                                                                                   LOAAccessTypeDescription = loa.LOAAccessTypeDescription, 
                                                                                   PersonType = loa.PersonType,
                                                                                    LOAName = loa.LOAName,

DateAdded = DateTime.Parse(loa.DateAdded.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 });
```

But I'm at a loss on how to add the last two queries - first I tried wrapping it in brackets and adding a .Union which didn't work, and then when I tried to nest them with appropriate .ToLists, that didn't work either.

Below is the code to bind it to the repeater.

```
 rptLOA.DataSource = qryMultipleLOA;
            rptLOA.DataBind();
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like?

```
var qryMultipleLOA = qryIssuer.Union(qryEMD).Union(qryEmdRep).Union(qryLOAPerson).ToList();
```

Provided your queries' footprints are the same, this shouldn't be an issue to chain them upon each other.

Edit:

I would also recommend the following:

1. Create a class to hold an instance of the resultant data.
2. Instead of creating lists of dynamic variables generated from Linq and hoping they all match, funnel the linq results into a List. That way you can tell immediately if you have a type mismatch.
3. Once you have four lists of the same List, Unions as per my syntax above will be a snap.

Dynamic Linq lists can be a pain, unwieldy and a single property type change can throw of your code at runtime rather than design time. If you follow the steps above, your code will be much more maintainable and clear to you and others.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either - the error I got was: "NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code - Only primitive types such as 'Int32, String and Guid' are supported in this context.

Comment: Ok, I did a variation of your suggestion - did use a class (ExtendedLOA) and put all results into a list, which worked :) Thanks very much!